# Why does my TTS crash when using gesture, but fine if using buttons?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

so i have the following code that works just fine if i use the next or previous button to change the content i have loaded and the tts to read the content.  If i use the gesture to change the value of the progressL1 int then the whole app crashes and tts never works.  Strange behavious is that if i press the next (or previous button) then use gestures after tts works fine and the app doesnt crash.

What i think might be happening is the Public void onInit() never gets called if i use just gestures to advance the content (progressL1++), but i dont know how to get around this.  Im new to java and android dev so have hit this as a wall and dont know how to progress.

The code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;

public class Lessonsinglegroup extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener, android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {


//define the image and text view for use later
ImageView Image;
TextView Text;

//define the texttospeak stuff

private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
public int progressL1 = 0;
private TextView inputText;
private TextToSpeech tts;
private ImageButton speakButton;
private ImageButton nextButton;
private ImageButton previousButton;
private Button babout;
private Button bhome;

//deal with the swipe to advance
private GestureDetector gDetector;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lessonsinglegroup);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //link the image and text boxes to the xml
    Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    loadDataFromAsset(progressL1);

    gDetector = new GestureDetector(this);


    //finish with the asset load

    //define tts stuff
    inputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    inputText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    speakButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtalk);
    nextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibnext);
    previousButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibprevious);
    babout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.babout);   //about button
    bhome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bhome);   //about button

    //new onclick listener style

    speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    previousButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    babout.setOnClickListener(this);
    bhome.setOnClickListener(this);
}
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v==babout) {
            Intent startabout = new Intent(Lessonsinglegroup.this, AboutScreen.class); //this is about screen
            startActivity(startabout);
        }

        if (v==bhome) {
            Intent startabout = new Intent(Lessonsinglegroup.this, Main.class); //this is main screen
            startActivity(startabout);
        }

        if (v==nextButton && progressL1==10) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Lessonsinglegroup.this, 
             "End of Lesson", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);           
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                LinearLayout toastview=(LinearLayout) toast.getView();
                ImageView imageCodeProject = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                imageCodeProject.setImageResource(R.drawable.lessoncomplete);  //logo name
                toastview.addView(imageCodeProject, 0);
                toast.show();
        }

        if (v==nextButton && progressL1<10) {
            progressL1++;
            //toast not required now its working
            // Toast.makeText(Lessonsinglegroup.this, "progress +1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Lessonsinglegroup.this.loadDataFromAsset(progressL1);
        }

        if (v==previousButton) {
            progressL1--;
            //toast not required now its working
            // Toast.makeText(Lessonsinglegroup.this, "progress +1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Lessonsinglegroup.this.loadDataFromAsset(progressL1);
        }

        if (v==speakButton){            
            String text = inputText.getText().toString();
            if (text!=null && text.length()>0) {
                tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        }

    };

    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

    }

    //gesture handling down here

    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;

    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float xVelocity, float yVelocity) {

            if (start.getRawX() > finish.getRawX() && (progressL1<10)) {
                      //swipe left action here
                    progressL1++;
                    Lessonsinglegroup.this.loadDataFromAsset(progressL1);
                 }    
            if (start.getRawX() > finish.getRawX() && (progressL1==10)) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Lessonsinglegroup.this, 
                         "End of Single Group Lesson", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);              
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            LinearLayout toastview=(LinearLayout) toast.getView();
                            ImageView imageCodeProject = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                            imageCodeProject.setImageResource(R.drawable.lessoncomplete);  //logo name
                            toastview.addView(imageCodeProject, 0);
                            toast.show();
                } 
            if (start.getRawX() < finish.getRawX()) { 
                //swipe rightaction here
                    progressL1--;
                    Lessonsinglegroup.this.loadDataFromAsset(progressL1);
                 }    
           return true;

    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2, float arg3) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return false;
    }

    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
        }

    //end of gesture based advance


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
        //sucess with TTS create it
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
    else {
        //missing TTS so install it
        Intent installIntent = new Intent();
        installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(installIntent);
    }
}


}

public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(Lessonsinglegroup.this, "Text to Speech initialised", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(Lessonsinglegroup.this, "Error starting Text to Speech", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//actually load the text file and image file   
public void loadDataFromAsset(int progressL1) {
    //load the asset files themselves
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("lessons/singlegp/" + progressL1 + ".txt");
        //check file size
        int size = is.available();
        //create a buffer to handle it
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        //send the data to the buffer
        is.read(buffer);
        //close the stream down
        is.close();
        //set the text we recovered to the TextView
        Text.setText(new String(buffer));

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        return;
    }

    //image file next
    try {
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("lessons/singlegp/" + progressL1 + ".jpg");
        //load the image as drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims,  null);
        //set the drawable image to the imageview
        Image.setImageDrawable(d);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        return;
            }
      }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_lessonsinglegroup, menu);
    return true;
}  

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Im not sure if this is the 'best' way to code what i want but it works all but the TTS when only gestures are used to change progressL1 value.  NO idea why, please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone able to even offer a  hint why this might be crashing?

Answer (score 0):

What does your logcat says? In my  case I had problems with gesture listener because it somehow makes a queue of events, and the events start pilling up if you do the gesture really quick and when android tries to run All the events it gives a crash due i think to running out of memory. So check the logcat and copy paste the error log. If it's like the errror i have maybe i can help.

Comment: Thanks, on checking back through the code I had actually missed the intent to launch tts after the gesture hence the crash.